# How to group a pandas dataframe by array intersection

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, networkx, graph-theory

Say I have a DataFrame like below

```
  UUID             domains
0  asd   [foo.com, foo.ca]
1  jkl    [foo.ca, foo.fr]
2  xyz            [foo.fr]
3  iek  [bar.com, bar.org]
4  qkr           [bar.org]
5  kij          [buzz.net]
```

How can I turn it in to something like this?

```
  UUID
0  [asd, jkl, xyz]
1  [iek, qkr]
2  [kij]
```

I want to group all the UUIDs where any domain is present in any other `domains` column. For example, rows `0` and `1` both contain `foo.ca` and rows `1` and `2` both contain `foo.fr` so should be grouped together.

The size of my data set is millions of rows so I can't brute force it.

Comment: Please provide the DataFrame constructor, the format is ambiguous (strings? lists?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the following input with domains as lists:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'UUID': ['asd', 'jkl', 'xyz', 'iek', 'qkr', 'kij'],
                   'domains': [['foo.com', 'foo.ca'], ['foo.ca', 'foo.fr'], ['foo.fr'], ['bar.com', 'bar.org'], ['bar.org'], ['buzz.net']]}
                 )
```

You problem is a graph problem. You want to find the roots of the disconnected subgraphs:

[image: graph]

This is easily achieved with [`networkx`](https://networkx.org).

```
# transform dataframe into graph
import networkx as nx
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df.explode('domains'),
                            source='UUID', target='domains',
                            create_using=nx.DiGraph)

# split the subgraphs (weakly_connected) and find the roots (degree: 0)
# the output is a generator
groups = ([n for n,g in G.subgraph(c).in_degree if g==0]
          for c in nx.weakly_connected_components(G))

# transform the generator to Series
s = pd.Series(groups)
```

output:

```
0    [asd, jkl, xyz]
1         [iek, qkr]
2              [kij]
```

Comment: Great, thanks. This is along the lines I was thinking. I'll update the question with some more context and what I've tried so far.

How performant is this going to be? I have around 20 million rows of data to process. I think I can reduce the size of the data by grouping the exploded dataframe by the `domain` column and aggregating the `id` column. I can discard all the rows that only have a single ID because they don't have any relations.

Comment: @Iain It is difficult to answer without having the actual data. It certainly depends on how many groups, node per group, single rows, etc you have. Why don't you give it a try on a 1% sample, then 10% sample to see if it scales? I would certainly be interested in feedback ;)

Comment: Apologies for the delay getting back to you here. The data set I have is about 15M rows with the average `domains` column having 3 items. It's about 2GB in memory when loaded in to in a DataFrame. Running the example code on an r5.2xl EC2 instance (64GB RAM, 8vCPU) took around 8 minutes. It consumed around 36GB during this time.

Answer (score 2):

We can do `explode` first then use `networkx`

```
import networkx as nx
s = df.explode('domains')
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(s, 'UUID', 'domains')
out = pd.Series([[y for y in x if y not in s.domains.tolist()] for x in [*nx.connected_components(G)]])
Out[209]: 
0    [xyz, jkl, asd]
1         [iek, qkr]
2              [kij]
dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks. How will this scale to handling millions of rows?